# Cancelling a Camel message

Tags: java, rest, soap, apache-camel

I support an application that operates as a routing hub for SOAP and RESTful messages utilizing Apache Camel.  We have some rather complex routing rules implemented.  There is a user interface where administrators can monitor the messages that are coming through the hub and what their statuses are.  I have a request for an enhancement that will allow the user to request a delete on any request that is in process.  This is usually a request where the send failed for whatever reason and Camel has queued it for a re-delivery.

One of the developers added some code that would delete the specific message from the inflight repository and changed the status on our repository to cancelled..  I have found that Camel will attempt to re-deliver the message anyway until it hits the maximum retry count and the message ends up with a failed status instead of cancelled.

The code that is in place is:

```
@Override
@Asynchronous
public void cancelExchange(String exchangeId) {
    synchronized (this.camelContext) {
        // Get a list of all in flight exchanges with the passed in exchangeId
        final List<Exchange> exchanges = this.camelContext.getInflightRepository().browse().stream().filter(inflightExchange -> inflightExchange.getExchange().getExchangeId().equals(exchangeId))
                .map(InflightRepository.InflightExchange::getExchange).collect(Collectors.toList());

        // Remove any active exchanges from Camel
        for (final Exchange exchange : exchanges) {
            this.log.debug("Removing exchange {}", exchange.getExchangeId());

            this.camelContext.getInflightRepository().remove(exchange);

            // Set the ROUTE_STOP property so Camel will try to stop the Exchange on the next
            // retry
            exchange.setProperty(Exchange.ROUTE_STOP, Boolean.TRUE);
        }

        // Set the ExchangeMessage status to canceled
        final Optional<ExchangeMessage> optionalExchangeMessage = this.messageService.findOneByExchangeId(exchangeId);

        if (optionalExchangeMessage.isPresent()) {
            this.messageService.setProcessingStatus(optionalExchangeMessage.get(), ProcessingStatus.CANCELLED, null);
        }
    }
}
```

I'll have to admit I was surprised to see the message re-appear since it was supposedly deleted from the queue.  Where did we go wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting InterruptedException as exception on the cancelled
exchange as well, this should be detected by the redelivery error
handler and break out, eg

```
exchange.setException(new InterruptedException("Cancel Exchange"));
exchange.setProperty(Exchange.ROUTE_STOP, Boolean.TRUE);
```

Comment: I tried that.  However, while I was out for the holidays one of the other developers completely removed Camel and wrote the message management with custom code.